# angularJS variable in div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem actually with a view from my AngularJS web app.

So I have this in my view:

```
<div class="xe-widget xe-counter" data-count=".num" data-from="0" data-to="{{ users }}" data-suffix=" / 30" data-duration="2">
        <div class="xe-icon">
            <i class="linecons-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="xe-label">
            <strong class="num">0</strong>
            <span>Joueurs en ligne</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my controller I added this:

```
$scope.users = 10;
```

But the problem is that the data-to="{{ users }}" in the div, don't seem to work.. When I try to replace data-to="{{ users }}" with a static value like: data-to=10; it's working.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Here is the directive of the counter

```
directive('xeCounter', function(){

    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs)
        {
            var $el = angular.element(el),
                sm = scrollMonitor.create(el);

            sm.fullyEnterViewport(function()
            {
                var opts = {
                    useEasing:      attrDefault($el, 'easing', true),
                    useGrouping:    attrDefault($el, 'grouping', true),
                    separator:      attrDefault($el, 'separator', ','),
                    decimal:        attrDefault($el, 'decimal', '.'),
                    prefix:         attrDefault($el, 'prefix', ''),
                    suffix:         attrDefault($el, 'suffix', ''),
                },
                $count      = attrDefault($el, 'count', 'this') == 'this' ? $el : $el.find($el.data('count')),
                from        = attrDefault($el, 'from', 0),
                to          = attrDefault($el, 'to', 100),
                duration    = attrDefault($el, 'duration', 2.5),
                delay       = attrDefault($el, 'delay', 0),
                decimals    = new String(to).match(/\.([0-9]+)/) ? new String(to).match(/\.([0-9]+)$/)[1].length : 0,
                counter     = new countUp($count.get(0), from, to, decimals, duration, opts);
                setTimeout(function(){ counter.start(); }, delay * 1000);
                //alert(to); --> Printing {{users}}
                sm.destroy();
            });
        }
    };
}).
```

I added the alert(to); to check if the value was correctly sent but I get the {{users}} instead of the value..

Comment: `{{user}}` -> `{{users}}` ?

Comment: Fixed, but same. It's not working. Same result :x

Comment: What happens with this html construct? I guess there is some js that does something with it (directive etc.)... maybe the problem is a race condition? Also, have you put the placeholder somewhere else just to see if it's displayed correctly?

Comment: I tried by replacing {{ users }} by 10 per exemple. And it's worked correctly

Comment: Did you add the `ng-controller` attribute somewhere?

Comment: You already said that, we have to know what "worked" means. What happens with this html?

Comment: The controller is already included in the page. I checked by printing {{ users }} on the page and it's showed me the correct value. And the html is a animated counter.

Comment: Any chance users are not ready at the moment the DOM renders?

Comment: How can I check this ?

Comment: If you are fetching users via an ajax call (or any async call), then they are probably just `undefined` at the time the DOM renders.

Comment: I checked the HTML Source with the browser and the value is correctly injected look: http://prntscr.com/5gje8v

Comment: Too drunk to answer :) Christmasholidasy in Denmark. But go for `ng-if` this will solve your problem, I am sure - one way or another.

Comment: Outch, if someone know the answer. Please, help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You must include an ng-controller to tell angular where to look for your scope variable.  Try adding an ng-controller attribute to your view

```
<div ng-controller="YourController" class="xe-widget xe-counter" data-count=".num" data-from="0" data-to="{{ users }}" data-suffix=" / 30" data-duration="2">
    <div class="xe-icon">
        <i class="linecons-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="xe-label">
        <strong class="num">0</strong>
        <span>Joueurs en ligne</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me with my code how it should look ? Thank's you

Answer (score 0):

I think that is too late for you, but it can be useful for other guys.

Replace yours directive for this:

```
directive('xeCounter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

            var $el = angular.element(el),
                sm = scrollMonitor.create(el);

            sm.fullyEnterViewport(function () {
                var opts = {
                        useEasing: attrDefault($el, 'easing', true),
                        useGrouping: attrDefault($el, 'grouping', true),
                        separator: attrDefault($el, 'separator', ','),
                        decimal: attrDefault($el, 'decimal', '.'),
                        prefix: attrDefault($el, 'prefix', ''),
                        suffix: attrDefault($el, 'suffix', '')
                    },
                    $count = attrDefault($el, 'count', 'this') == 'this' ? $el : $el.find($el.data('count')),
                    from = attrs.from ? attrs.from : 0,
                    to = attrs.to ? attrs.to : 100,
                    duration = attrs.duration ? attrs.duration : 2.5,
                    delay = attrs.delay ? attrs.delay : 0,
                    decimals = String(to).match(/\.([0-9]+)/) ? String(to).match(/\.([0-9]+)$/)[1].length : 0,
                    counter = new countUp($count.get(0), from, to, decimals, duration, opts);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    counter.start();
                }, delay * 1000);

                sm.destroy();
            });
        }
    };
}).
```

And the HTML should stay like this:

```
<div class="xe-widget xe-counter" xe-counter data-count=".num" data-from="0" data-to="{{ total }}" data-suffix="" data-duration="5">
<div class="xe-icon"><i class="linecons-cup" /></div>
<div class="xe-label"><strong class="num">0</strong><span>TOTAL</span></div>
</div>
```

Be shure that the **$scope.total** variable is declared and its value is an number.